# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects' error when getting data from request object

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

So i am trying to make a reset password functionality in django but getting this error, can't debug it.

So this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aman/.local/share/virtualenvs/stet-sikkim-project-D4VwjO1D/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/aman/.local/share/virtualenvs/stet-sikkim-project-D4VwjO1D/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/aman/.local/share/virtualenvs/stet-sikkim-project-D4VwjO1D/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/aman/.local/share/virtualenvs/stet-sikkim-project-D4VwjO1D/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aman/.local/share/virtualenvs/stet-sikkim-project-D4VwjO1D/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aman/Desktop/stet-sikkim-project/authentication/views.py", line 184, in post
    user = request.objects.filter(email=email)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /authentication/request-password
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

This is the code,

```
class RequestPasswordResetEmail(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'authentication/reset-password.html')

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.POST['email']
        context = {
            'values': request.POST
        }

        if not validate_email(email):
            messages.error(request, 'Please enter a valid email')
            return render(request, 'authentication/reset-password.html', context)

        current_site = get_current_site(request)

        user = request.objects.filter(email=email)

        if user.exists():
            email_contents = {
                'user': user[0],
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user[0].pk)),
                'token': PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user[0]),
            }

            link = reverse('reset-user-password', kwargs={
                'uidb64': email_contents['uid'], 'token': email_contents['token']})

            email_subject = 'Password Reset STET Sikkim'

            reset_url = 'http://'+current_site.domain+link

            email = EmailMessage(
                email_subject,
                'Please click the link below to reset your password, ignore if you did not made this request\n'+reset_url,
                'noreply@stetsikkim.com',
                [email],
            )

        email.send(fail_silently=False)
        messages.success(
            request, 'We have sent you an email to reset your password')

        return render(request, 'authentication/reset-password.html')
```

Why is this error happening, i can't find any solution on stack overflow and unable to debug, help if see any mistake in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = request.objects.filter(email=email)
```

request is not a models, you need to user models ( the models you want to filter )

```
user = User.objects.filter(email=email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure if you still need an answer but i'll put it in here for others in the future.

```
user = request.objects.filter(email=email)
```

So I am guessing that you are trying to get a specific email inorder to generate a password reset token for that specific user. But the code above doesnot make sense since there is no model to look for a user with the specific email you provided. The proper line of code to write will be:

```
 user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
```

I have added the .first() because judging from your positional argument Iam guessing you want the first result but the way you wrote it the error User object is subscriptable will occur thus using .first()

Also another error will occur saying User has no attribute 'exists', so the remedy I suggest is using this line of code:

```
if user.pk is not None:
```

instead of the one you used. Basically it is saying that if the primary key for the user is available then execute the following code.

I know this probably isn't the best of explanations but I hope it helps. Cheers!