# How can I resolve this error? : 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to create a web app for managing expenses for a company but
I ran into a problem that I quite don't know how to work around it. The error
message is `'WGSIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects'`. I am new in python
that's why it is stressing me out. I have linked the line that spawns the error
as well as my views.py file as well as my urls.py.

The error:

```
'WGSIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Line associated with error:

```
user = request.objects.filter(email=email)
```

My view.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import View
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from validate_email import validate_email
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib import auth
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_str, DjangoUnicodeDecodeError
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.urls import reverse
from .utils import token_generator
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator


# Create your views here.


class EmailValidationView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data=json.loads(request.body)
        email=data['email']
        if not validate_email(email):
            return JsonResponse({'email_error': 'Email is invalid'}, status=400)

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return JsonResponse({'email_error': 'Sorry email in use, choose another one'}, status=409)

        return JsonResponse({'email_valid': True})


class UsernameValidationView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data=json.loads(request.body)
        username=data['username']
        if not str(username).isalnum():
            return JsonResponse({'username_error': 'username should only contain alphanumeric characters'}, status=400)

        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            return JsonResponse({'username_error': 'Sorry username in use, choose another one'}, status=409)

        return JsonResponse({'username_valid': True})


class RegistrationView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        context = {
            'fieldValues':request.POST
        }

        if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            if  not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                if len(password) < 6:
                    messages.error(request, 'password too short')
                    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', context)

                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()

                uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))

                domain = get_current_site(request).domain
                link = reverse('activate', kwargs={
                    'uidb64':uidb64, 'token':token_generator.make_token(user)})

                activate_url = 'http://' +domain + link
                email_subject = 'Activate your account'
                email_body = 'Hi' + " " + user.username + " " + 'Please use this link to verify your account\n' + activate_url
                email = EmailMessage(
                    email_subject,
                    email_body,
                    'noreply@semicolon.com',
                    [email],
                )
                email.send(fail_silently=False)
                messages.success(request, 'Account successfully created')
                return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')

        return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')


class VerificationView(View):
    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            id = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=id)

            if not token_generator.check_token(user, token):
                return redirect('login' + " " + '?message=' + " " + 'User already activated')

            if user.is_active:
                return redirect('login')
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Account activated successfully')
            return redirect('login')

        except Exception as ex:
            pass
        return redirect('login')


class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'authentication/login.html')

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        if username and password:
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    messages.success(request, 'Welcome, '+user.username+
                                     ' You are now logged in')
                    return redirect('expenses')
                messages.error(request, 'Account s not active, please check your email')
                return render(request, 'authentication/login.html')
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid credentials, Please try again')
            return render(request, 'authentication/login.html')
        messages.error(request, 'Please fill both fields ')
        return render(request, 'authentication/login.html')


class LogoutView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        auth.logout(request)
        messages.success(request, 'You have been logged out')
        return redirect('login')


class RequestPasswordResetEmail(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'authentication/reset-password.html')

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {
            'values': request.POST
        }

        if not validate_email(email):
            messages.error(request, 'Please provide a valid email')
            return render(request, 'authentication/reset-password.html', context)

        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        user = request.objects.filter(email=email)
        if user.exists():
            email_contents = {
                'user': user[0],
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user[0].pk)),
                'token': PasswordResetTokenGenerator.make_token(user[0]),
            }

            link = reverse('reset-user-password', kwargs={
                'uidb64': email_contents['uid'], 'token': email_contents['token']})

            email_subject = 'Password reset Instructions'

            reset_url = 'http://' + current_site.domain + link

            email = EmailMessage(
                email_subject,
                'Hi there, Please click the link below to reset your password \n' + reset_url,
                'noreply@semicolon.com',
                [email],
            )
            email.send(fail_silently=False)

        messages.success(request, 'We have sent you an email to reset your password')

        return render(request, 'authentication/reset-password.html')


class CompletePasswordReset(View):
    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):

        context = {
            'uidb64': uidb64,
            'token': token
        }
        return render(request, 'authentication/set-new-password.html', context)

    def post(self, request, uidb64, token):
        context = {
            'uidb64': uidb64,
            'token': token
        }
        return render(request, 'authentication/set-new-password.html',context)
```

My urls.py:

```
from .views import RegistrationView, VerificationView, UsernameValidationView, EmailValidationView, LoginView, LogoutView, RequestPasswordResetEmail, CompletePasswordReset
from django.urls import path
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    path('register',RegistrationView.as_view(),name="register"),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('validate-username',csrf_exempt(UsernameValidationView.as_view()),
         name='validate-username'),
    path('validate-email',csrf_exempt(EmailValidationView.as_view()),
         name='validate_email'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>', VerificationView.as_view(),
         name="activate"),
    path('set-new-password/<uidb64>/<token>', CompletePasswordReset.as_view(),
         name="reset-user-password"),
    path('request-reset-link', RequestPasswordResetEmail.as_view(),
         name="request-password")
]
```

If anyone wants any additional information, please ask. Thanks in advance.

I am kind of a beginner to coding and so I tend to have trouble when it comes to troubleshooting so there isn't much i tried to change other than running it with and without the .request but still nothing. I do have a feeling that the problem is very minimal. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'objects' error when getting data from request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204458/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-objects-error-when-getting-data-from-req)

Comment: `request.objects.filter(email=email)` makes no sense.

Comment: I did try to use that method but apparently I get this error too (PasswordResetTokenGenerator.make_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user')

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure out the answer, the problems and remedies are as follows:

1. Initially I used this line of code:

`user = request.objects.filter(email=email)`

but it is wrong instead I had to change it to:

```
user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
```

2. After changing the above code, another error was saying User has no attribute that exists which then I had to change to:

`if user.pk is not None:`

3. Then it showed an error that the PasswordResetTokenGenerator was missing an argument 'user' which was confusing at first since I clearly was passing it into the function, but I then realised that it was a small error that I did not put the parenthesis after the PasswordResetTokenGenerator which is kind of clumsy.

Therefore the complete corrected block is:

```
user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

if user.pk is not None:
    email_contents = {
        'user': user,
        'domain': current_site.domain,
        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        'token': PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user),
    }
```